# how to get out from admin/text mode

Tags: command-line, gdm

I have literaly no idea on what happened and what are the next steps.
I've installed the upgrade to 18.04.1 LTS after restarting computer I found myself in admin (?)/text (? - I even don't know the proper name).

It asks me to log in.
Apparently I enter the correct data.
Than it shows:

```
XXX@XXX:~$
```

what should I type? Kind request for 6-year old level answer, my coding understanding is probably even not at that level.

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, exit, ~Desktop - did not work. It comes back to login and password request.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like you're getting a TTY instead of the GUI login screen (GDM). What Ubuntu version were you using before? Were there any problems during the upgrade?

Comment: Very good question, I have no idea what was the previous one. Sorry. But it is true there is TTY info.

Comment: No problems (or at least no apparent to me) during upgrade.

Comment: So, I run all the suggested commands. It (I mean the device) gave me, generally speaking, "all field" response to any try. An hour passed. Partly devastated I look  time at TTY (new word - thanks LeonidMew!) nothing changed. While moving it I accidentally turned off the wi-fi button and than instinctively turned it back on. Some new strange/scary info appeared on my TTY. So, pannic buttons configuration was pressed (CTRL+ALT+DEL) and... IT WARKS AGAIN! I am back in GIU. THANK YOU ALL! You are fantastic!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you get into text console after boot up? Try to login and type `startx` - it should get you to graphical environment. Its a temporal solution, if it works.

May be something wrong with greeter, if above runs fine, try reinstall it: `sudo apt-get --reinstall install gdm3`
Also do run `sudo systemctl enable graphical.target`

Comment: I did runsudo apt-get --reinstall install gdm3

Comment: one of many info I received back is: gdm.service is not active, cannot reload. I also tried  sudo systemctl enable graphical.target - it faild too. It says: the unit files have no installation config [....], This means you are not meant to be enabled using systemctl.

Comment: So, I run all the suggested commands. It (I mean the device) gave me, generally speaking, "all field" response to any try. An hour passed. Partly devastated I look  time at TTY (new word - thanks LeonidMew!) nothing changed. While moving it I accidentally turned off the wi-fi button and than instinctively turned it back on. Some new strange/scary info appeared on my TTY. So, pannic buttons configuration was pressed (CTRL+ALT+DEL) and... IT WARKS AGAIN! I am back in GIU. THANK YOU ALL! You are fantastic!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you set the default target on your machine to something other than graphical.  Try

```
sudo systemctl enable graphical.target
```

and then reboot and see what happens.

Comment: I've tried - failed. it says:  the unit files have no installation config [....], This means you are not meant to be enabled using systemctl.

Comment: So, I run all the suggested commands. It (I mean the device) gave me, generally speaking, "all field" response to any try. An hour passed. Partly devastated I look  time at TTY (new word - thanks LeonidMew!) nothing changed. While moving it I accidentally turned off the wi-fi button and than instinctively turned it back on. Some new strange/scary info appeared on my TTY. So, pannic buttons configuration was pressed (CTRL+ALT+DEL) and... IT WARKS AGAIN! I am back in GIU. THANK YOU ALL! You are fantastic!

Answer (score 0):

So, I run all the suggested commands. It (I mean the device) gave me, generally speaking, "all field" response to any try. An hour passed. Partly devastated I looked  time at TTY (new word - thanks LeonidMew!) nothing changed. While moving it I accidentally turned off the wi-fi button and than instinctively turned it back on. Some new strange/scary info appeared on my TTY. So, pannic buttons configuration was pressed (CTRL+ALT+DEL) and... IT WARKS AGAIN! I am back in GIU. Thank,I love you guys. You are fantastic!

Comment: So some of suggested commands helps, and after reboot it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

Open a text-only virtual console by using the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>.

Press the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to exit the virtual console.